# Chrome extension content scripts are not injected in the first place, how to debug?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

When I'm running the Chromium browser using:

> chromium-browser --load-extension=/path/to/my/extension
>   --user-data-dir=/path/to/chrome/profile --app=http://localhost/somepage

some content scripts are not injected into the page. These scripts are defined as follows in the manifest file:

```
"content_scripts" : [{
                "matches" : [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
                "js" : [ "content/s1.js", "content/s2.js", "content/s3.js", "content/s4.js" ],
                "run_at" : "document_end"
}]
```

When inspecting the page, I see that only `s1.js` and `s4.js` were injected successfully. After reloading the page all scripts are injected correctly, and my extension works as expected.

What can be the reason for that, and how to debug this?

**Edit:**

Those content scripts (that fail to inject sometimes) reference 'document' at the beginning. It seems like if I wrap them into something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { document. ... }, 5000);
```

They are always injected as expected. Is it possible that the document is not available, even though "run_at": "document_end" was specified in manifest?

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed this too.  I believe this is the reason I wasn't able to use JQuery's document.ready function.

Answer (score 1):

You can better do this:

Create 1 content.js script:

```
/* inject script */
try {
var script1 = document.createElement("script");script1.type = "text/javascript";script1.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/js/injected1.js");document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script1);
var script2 = document.createElement("script");script2.type = "text/javascript";script2.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/js/injected2.js");document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script2);
var script3 = document.createElement("script");script3.type = "text/javascript";script3.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/js/injected3.js");document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script3);
var script4 = document.createElement("script");script4.type = "text/javascript";script4.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/js/injected4.js");document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script4);
} catch(e) {}
```

in the manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts" : [{
            "matches" : [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
            "js" : [ "content.js" ],
            "run_at" : "document_end"
```

}]